# how to Mock xyz.capybara.clamav.commands.scan.result.ScanResult getStatus Method

Tags: junit

Following is the Code I have:

```
ClamavClient client = new ClamavClient(clamdHost, clamdPort);
ScanResult result = client.scan(inputStream);
String status = result.getStatus().toString();
```

I want to Mock "result.getStatus()". I am using PowerMockito to Mock ScanResult

```
ScanResult mockScanResult = Mockito.mock(ScanResult.class);
when(mockClamavClient.scan(mockFileInputStream)).thenReturn(mockScanResult);
```

Does anyone know the answer, appreciate your help in advance.

Comment: is there any error you get?

Comment: It is giving null pointer exception when it excutes "result.getStatus()", as the following statement is now working properly "when(mockClamavClient.scan(mockFileInputStream)).thenReturn(mockScanResult);"

Answer (score -1):

The scan method is final so can't be mocked.

Comment: This is wrong. PowerMockito can mock final method just be sure ```org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock()``` method used instead of Mockito's api